# How do I set my keyboard layout to work like the Windows mnemonic Russian keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, russian

This is the mnemonic Russian keyboard in Windows.

[image: This]

while this is the phonetic Russian layout in Ubuntu.

[image: this]

In Windows there are some Russian characters mapped in different keys and also:

From Wikipedia:

> Windows 10 includes its own implementation of a mnemonic QWERTY-based
>   input method for Russian, which does not fully rely on assigning a key
>   to every Russian letter, but uses the sh, sc, ch, ya (ja), yu (ju), ye
>   (je), yo (jo) combinations to input ш, щ, ч, я, ю, э and ё
>   respectively.

Comment: That Windows behavior sounds like some kind of input method to me rather than a plain keyboard layout. Have you checked out the Russian input methods provided by the `ibus-m17n` package?

Comment: I was thinking that this could be achieved turning the ' s'  and 'y' in dead keys, but I don't know how. 

I've checked the input methods in the ibus-m17n packet and there is a IM similar to what I want, but it is not similar enough to what I need.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, you should better to explain in details, what you expected and what you are getting. e.g. `ju` type `ж` or `je` type `я`. But I prefer to type one key than two or more keys.

Answer (score 0):

One way to come close to the desired behavior is to

1. Define a [compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#compose)
2. Create the file `~/.XCompose`
3. Add the desired compose sequences to `~/.XCompose`
4. Relogin

I tested it with a `~/.XCompose` file with only this line:

```
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_es> <Cyrillic_ha> : "ш" Cyrillic_sha # CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER SHA
```

When using the *Russian (phonetic)* keyboard layout it lets me do:

<kbd>Compose</kbd> followed by <kbd>С</kbd> followed by <kbd>Х</kbd> -> ш