# How to install the яшерты russian phonetic keyboard in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

This is yet another question on the subject, the others were closed, but without providing enough help to get me going.

So, when I go to Language and Region settings I can install a **яверты** Russian phonetic keyboard, i.e. a Russian keyboard where **qwerty** maps to **яверты**. This mapping never made much sense to me, I would like to use a keyboard where **qwerty** maps to **яшерты**.

I found only scarce pieces of information on the web on how to do it and all implied some level of prior knowledge. I have none. I am comfortable with the command line, though.

Can anyone provide a detailed guide on how this can be achieved or a link to such a guide? Please, assume zero knowledge on the subject of mapping keyboards in linux.

Comment: I don't see any either, follow this to add a custom layout: https://askubuntu.com/q/482678/480481. To me **яверты** makes more sense than **яшерты** as Russian **в** is *phonetically* close to English **v** / **w**, and English **w** is *phonetically* nowhere near Russian **ш** ('sh'). So **в** for **w** key is *phonetically* more consistent than **ш** for **w** key IMO.

Comment: It is a habit...

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1011920).

Answer (score 0):

If your are using X11/Xorg, you can just do:

$ setxkbmap -layout ru -variant phonetic_mac

Then, you will have the same keyboard as mac does (яшерты)

See also: /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ru

Regards!